# Debezium is replicating tables not included in "table.include.list"

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have specified a list of tables to be replicated in Debezium, using the "table.include.list" configuration.

However when creating new tables in the source db, that have not been selected for replication, they are in fact being replicated.

How can I change this behaviour of Debezium, to only replicate the tables specified?

Comment: Please provide some more information about your problem

Comment: Hi @NiclasGleesborg, I have 8 tables within a test database. When deploying the connector configuration, I only specified 5 of those tables to be replicated using the `table.include.list` configuration. However, all 8 tables are being replicated.

Comment: What Debezium version do you use? `table.include.list` was introduced only recently, the previous name for the parameter was `table.whitelist`.

Comment: Thanks @JiriPechanec - Version 1.2 is being used and the parameter to use is `table.whitelist`

Comment: Try using `table.include.list` instead of `table.whitelist`. Documenation: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver.html